# How to pass whole object to input from md-autocomplete angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

Generally i have an object of objects -> `filteredDrivers`.

Single object looks like this:

`DRIVER_ID: 99
 DRIVER_NAME: "JOHN SNOW"`

which i'm using in md-autocomplete:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input type="text"
         name="driver"
         mdInput
         [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
         placeholder="Driver"
         ngModel
         >
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let driver of filteredDrivers| async" [value]="driver"  
             ngDefaultControl>
    {{ driver.DRIVER_NAME}}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

And i want to pass whole object by submitting a form but in input i want to view just driver.DRIVER_NAME.

If i pass whole driver like `[value]="driver"` in input i see `[object Object]`
and form submit gives me full object

but when i go with `[value]="driver.DRIVER_NAME"` i can see what i want - `JOHN SNOW` but form submit gives me only `driver.DRIVER_NAME`

How can i pass whole object by submitting the form and see only `driver.DRIVER_NAME` property in input?

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: I think i can't cause i need whole angular project for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly documented in the Angular Material docs for
[Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview).

Specifically:

> Setting separate control and display values
>
> If you want the option's control value (what is saved in the form) to
>   be different than the option's display value (what is displayed in the
>   actual text field), you'll need to set the displayWith property on
>   your autocomplete element. A common use case for this might be if you
>   want to save your data as an object, but display just one of the
>   option's string properties.
>
> To make this work, create a function on your component class that maps
>   the control value to the desired display value. Then bind it to the
>   autocomplete's displayWith property.
>
> ```
> <md-input-container>
>    <input type="text" mdInput [formControl]="myControl" [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
> </md-input-container>
>
> <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
>    <md-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
>       {{ option.name }}
>    </md-option>
> </md-autocomplete>
> ```

Comment: That's the answer, sorry to bother i'm blind :) Thank you so much!

Comment: What if we want the option's control value (what is saved in the form) to be driver.id  and option's display value (what is displayed in the actual text field) to be driver.name?